# Bukkit interactable menu - page scrolling

Tags: java, plugins, bukkit, inventory

The project I am working on is an interact able Inventory menu Bukkit plugin for Minecraft.

The features I intend to have in this include:
- Being able to spawn items from catalog of items contained within an inventory (this is done and works)
- Interact with the menu (this is what I'm working on)

Specifically I'm trying to make two buttons (items) in the inventory scroll between different pages (previous and next page). I need to do this since the max amount of items in this inventory can only ever be 45 and the spawn able items contain 40 slots out of 45. The other 5 are used up by an exit button (works), a back button(works/navigates to a previous menu), the two page switcher buttons(doesn't work), and a blank space.

My problem is that I cannot get the switcher buttons to properly go back to the previous page of items and or the next page of items.

The catalog is meant to be one that can grow so the amount of items in the catalog is not a constant value.

I have confirmed that my code below does make 3 different inventories (test catalog of 86 items) but I cannot manage to make each inventory go to the previous or the next. I've gotten it to scroll between different inventories but only ever between inventory at(0) and at(2) or at(1) and at(2).

Some specific behavior of the snippet of code down below is that for some reason when the click event is called, the whole thing gets run x amount of times. I'm just not understanding why it would loop on click when this is ran only once for the purpose of setting the values of whiteCatalog.

EDIT: I can open up each individual inventory manually by doing whiteCatalog[0 through 2].open(. . . ) but when ever I try math in the index, I get weird results of the menu just skipping over to index one or two.

```
    YamlConfiguration test = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(Main.bannerCatalogs[0]);
    int x = (int) Math.ceil((double)test.getConfigurationSection("Banners").getKeys(false).size()/40);
    whiteCatalog = new InventoryMenu[x];
    for(int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        int offset = 0;
        final int k = i;
        offset = (40 * i);

        whiteCatalog[i] = new InventoryMenu("Banner Catalog: white", 45, Main.plug, i, new IMenuItemClicked()
        {   
            @Override
            public void onMenuItemClicked(MenuItemClicked clickEvent) 
            {   

                clickEvent.setCanClose(false);
                ItemStack clicked = clickEvent.getItemClicked();

                BTBUtil.log(Prefix.TEST + "Inventory ID: " + clickEvent.getMenu().id);

                if(clickEvent.getMenu().id == 0)
                {                       
                    if(clicked.getType() == Material.BANNER)
                        clickEvent.getPlayer().getInventory().addItem(clicked);
                    else if(clicked.getType() == Material.BARRIER)
                        clickEvent.getPlayer().closeInventory();
                    else if(clicked.getType() == Material.SPRUCE_DOOR_ITEM)
                        catalogSelect.open(clickEvent.getPlayer());
                }

                BTBUtil.log(Prefix.TEST + whiteCatalog.length);


                if(clicked.getType() == Material.STAINED_GLASS_PANE && clicked.getItemMeta().getDisplayName().equalsIgnoreCase("Previous Page"))
                {
                    whiteCatalog[clickEvent.getMenu().id-1].open(clickEvent.getPlayer());
                }
                else if(clicked.getType() == Material.STAINED_GLASS_PANE && clicked.getItemMeta().getDisplayName().equalsIgnoreCase("Next Page"))
                {
                    whiteCatalog[clickEvent.getMenu().id+1].open(clickEvent.getPlayer());
                }
            }
        }).loadItemsFromConfig(0, offset)
          .loadMenu();
    }       
}
```

Comment: I believe you'll have to create other instances of inventories for each of your pages, and open them accordingly. Similar to what you're doing with the back page

Comment: @Kerooker I need to use pagination but I'm just not sure how to properly implement that in this case.

Comment: You can create an inventory for each page, and when it's needed, you open that inventory

Answer (score 0):

Create classes for "Menu" and "Page". The "Page" class contains a own inventory and (maybe inherited) two buttons for up and down. In the menu you have a List with "Pages" and the current index. Then implement a Listener for InventoryInteract where you check the both buttons (items) to be clicked. Call a function in you Menu class where you open the "Page" inventory depending on the button click. For example: scrollDown() would decrement the index variable and then opens the page inventory out of the List(with the decremented index).
It's a littlebit more object oriented. To fill the pages you could iterate throug the items and add them to a page. The page class therefore should have an IsFull() and an AddItem() function. I think with you current approach you are on the right way.